# Xcode 6 localization error

Tags: ios, localization, xcode6

I accidentally deleted localization files  , which resulted in the removal of Storyboard. I restore Storyboard from the Recycle Bin and add it back to the project. Then in Storyboard File Inspector i pressed the "Localize" button...
Next i go to my project info and add to them localization files (interface Builder Storyboard)... Then I made changes to the view in localiztion storyboard. Run the project in the emulator. In the emulator everything works fine. Text in View changes depending on the selected language... All greate. But when I try to run the project on the iphone localization does not occur. I also noticed that even if i change Main.Storyboard (Base) any changes in the View on  Iphone did not change. Even if I delete any picture also view did not change. But in emulator all works great. I tried to remove the application from the iPhone, but it has no effect. I also installed the app on another iPhone, and it also does not give effect. Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Rename storyboard file.
2. Reconnect storyboard in project.
3. Done.